# Why does the database of an HADR standby server deactivate automatically?

Tags: unix, db2, sap-ase, sap-erp

I'm trying to configure SAP HADR with a primary and standby server. The configuration seems to be O.K. but the database of the standby server deactivates automatically. When I run the command `db2 activate database` in the standby server it is successfully activated but after a few seconds the database is deactivated again. In this scenario, nearsync of logs is inconsistent. Could someone please advise me what the possible cause of the deactivation might be?

SAP ECC6.0
DB6 9.1

Comment: I'm not familiar with the problem so can't offer a solution but you might get more luck on Server Fault than SO

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a programming problem or a server configuration problem. So, I'm trying it here too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

If a database was started by a CONNECT TO (or an implicit connect) and subsequently an ACTIVATE DATABASE is issued for that same database, then DEACTIVATE DATABASE must be used to shut down that database. **If ACTIVATE DATABASE was not used to start the database, the database will shut down when the last application disconnects**.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0021052.html